# order of document properties at insert

Tags: arangodb

If i'm not wrong, at inserting new document, ArangoDB does not care for order/sequence of object properties, is there a way to guarantee the order of properties same as they are declare in json object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't a way of ensuring the order of keys/attributes/properties in objects.

For ArangoDB, the following documents will be identical:

```
{ "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
{ "b" : 2, "a" : 1 }
```

and it may even return the keys/attributes/properties of the **same** document object in different orders.

If order of keys/attributes/properties is important, then the only way to ensure it is to use an array of values. This however will not allow access by named key/attribute/property but only by numeric index.